# Converting IQueryable<object> results to comma delimited string

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, iqueryable

I have a LINQ query that returns all absences for an employee.  The first part of the linq statement gets a basic list of the employees details, but I also return an IQueryable list of illnesses related to that absence.

I'd like to somehow convert that IQueryable list to a comma delimited list of Illnesses.

Currently I use (majorly stripped down):

```
DetailsOfSickness = (
  from t2 in Illnesses
  join ai1 in AbsenceIllnesses on t2.IllnessID equals ai1.IllnessID
  select new { Illness = ", " + t2.IllnessName })
```

Which returns the list but I'd like the results like: Headache, Flu, Cramps.... etc.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can to use `String.Join` to create your comma delimited string.

```
string DetailsOfSickness = 
    String.Join(", ", (
      from t2 in illnesses
      join ai1 in absenceIllnesses on t2.IllnessID equals ai1.IllnessID
      select t2.IllnessName).ToArray());
```

Comment: @Ecyrb, why not? I didn't tried, but as I included `.ToArray()` method, that should get your database values and, later, use them as parameter for `String.Join`

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should do it:

```
DetailsOfSickness = String.Join(", ", (
  from t2 in Illnesses
  join ai1 in AbsenceIllnesses on t2.IllnessID equals ai1.IllnessID
  select t2.IllnessName).ToArray());
```

- Please be aware, non-compiler, non-tested code.

Comment: Basically what I wrote kastermester but Rubens got in there first!  Thanks